# Benchmarking ArcPy / ArcMap Performance on different computers?

Tags: arcpy, performance, benchmark

This project came out of my need to build a justification for a faster work computer. Before asking for new equipment I want to be prepared to show the increase in performance by adding RAM or more processors. In order to achieve this I wrote a python script and tested it on different machines in my office. This is the process and results.

### **Data**

Streets - 1,805,375 records

Streets_table - 1,808,798 records

## **Code**

```
import platform, timeit, arcpy, time, csv, os, io

#get machine specs
name = platform.node()
processor = platform.machine()
oper_sys = platform.platform()
py_ver = platform.python_version()

#test loops
x = 0
start = timeit.timeit()
while x<=10000:
    foo = 1
    bar = 2
    foo+bar
    x=x+1
end = timeit.timeit()
tl = str(end-start)+'seconds to complete test loops'

#test make feature
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\PyTesting\data.gdb'
real_start = time.clock()
comp_start = timeit.timeit()
x=0
while x<=100:
    arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer('Streets','Streets_lyr')
    arcpy.management.Delete('Streets_lyr','Layer')
    x=x+1
comp_end = timeit.timeit()
real_end = time.clock()
comp_time = str(comp_end - comp_start)
real_time = (str(real_end - real_start))+' seconds'
mf_real = ('make feature real time: '+real_time)
mf_comp = 'make feature computer time: '+comp_time

#test join and calculate
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\PyTesting\data.gdb'
real_start = time.clock()
comp_start = timeit.timeit()
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer('Streets','Streets_lyr')
arcpy.management.MakeTableView('Streets_County','district_tbl')
arcpy.management.AddJoin('Streets_lyr','ID','district_tbl','ID')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="Streets_lyr", field="Streets.COUNTY", expression="!Streets_County.COUNTY!", expression_type="PYTHON", code_block="")
comp_end = timeit.timeit()
real_end = time.clock()
comp_time = str(comp_end - comp_start)
real_time = str(real_end - real_start)

jac_real = 'join and calculate real time: '+real_time
jac_comp = 'join and calculate computer time: '+comp_time

#test dissolve
real_start = time.clock()
comp_start = timeit.timeit()
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer('Streets','Streets_lyr_C3', "COUNTY = '03'")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features="Streets_lyr_C3", out_feature_class="Streets_C3_buffer", buffer_distance_or_field="100 Feet", line_side="FULL", line_end_type="ROUND", dissolve_option="NONE", dissolve_field="", method="PLANAR")
arcpy.management.Dissolve('Streets_d3_buffer','Streets_C3_buffer_diss','ST_NAME')
comp_end = timeit.timeit()
real_end = time.clock()
comp_time = str(comp_end - comp_start)
real_time = str(real_end - real_start)

dis_real = 'buffer and dissolve real time: '+real_time
dis_comp = 'buffer and dissolve computer time: '+comp_time

#write results to network file
location = r'c:\GIS\Pytesting'
note_name = name +'_'+ time.strftime('%m_%d_%y')+'.txt'
note = os.path.join(location,note_name)
f = io.open(note, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
f.write(u'Computer Name: '+name)
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write(u'Processor: '+processor)
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write('Operating System: '+oper_sys)
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write('Python Version: '+py_ver)
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write(time.strftime('%c'))
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write(tl)
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write(mf_real+u'\r\n'+mf_comp)
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write(jac_real+u'\r\n'+jac_comp)
f.write(u'\r\n')
f.write(dis_real+u'\r\n'+dis_comp)
f.close()

#reset environment
delete_list = ['Streets_C3_buffer','Streets_c3_buffer_diss','Streets_lyr','Streets_lyr_c3']
for item in delete_list:
    arcpy.management.Delete(item)
arcpy.management.Compact(arcpy.env.workspace)
```

## **Results**

**Computer 1**

> **Specs**
>
> Processor: AMD64
>
> Operating System: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
>
> Python Version: 2.7.10
>
> System Manufacturer    Dell Inc.
>
> System Model   Precision T7610
>
> System Type    x64-based PC
>
> Processor #1   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2637 v2 @ 3.50GHz, 3501 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
>
> Processor #2   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2637 v2 @ 3.50GHz, 3501 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
>
> Installed Physical Memory (RAM)    16.0 GB
>
> Total Physical Memory  15.9 GB
>
> Available Physical Memory  12.7 GB
>
> Total Virtual Memory   31.9 GB
>
> Available Virtual Memory   28.6 GB
>
> Page File Space    15.9 GB
>
> **Times**
>
> -0.00763508549659 seconds to complete test loops
>
> make feature real time: 38.0314714857 seconds
>
> make feature computer time: -0.000239311276225
>
> join and calculate real time: 549.478392039
>
> join and calculate computer time: 0.0045615779294
>
> buffer and dissolve real time: 589.134321079
>
> buffer and dissolve computer time: -0.00725412306065

**Computer #2**

> **Specs**
>
> Processor: AMD64
>
> Operating System: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
>
> Python Version: 2.7.8
>
> System Manufacturer    Dell Inc.
>
> System Model   Latitude E6540
>
> System Type    x64-based PC
>
> Processor  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4310M CPU @ 2.70GHz, 2701 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
>
> Installed Physical Memory (RAM)    8.00 GB
>
> Total Physical Memory  7.91 GB
>
> Available Physical Memory  5.47 GB
>
> Total Virtual Memory   15.8 GB
>
> Available Virtual Memory   12.9 GB
>
> Page File Space    7.91 GB
>
> **Times**
>
> -0.00420638742934 seconds to complete test loops
>
> make feature real time: 29.6121126168 seconds
>
> make feature computer time: -0.000301813809763
>
> join and calculate real time: 319.010255588
>
> join and calculate computer time: -2.47076796356e-05
>
> buffer and dissolve real time: 438.06708097
>
> buffer and dissolve computer time: -0.0164959872828

**Computer #3**

> **Specs**
>
> Processor: AMD64
>
> Operating System: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
>
> Python Version: 2.7.8
>
> System Manufacturer    Dell Inc.
>
> System Model   OptiPlex 990
>
> System Type    x64-based PC
>
> Processor  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz, 3101 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
>
> Installed Physical Memory (RAM)    8.00 GB
>
> Total Physical Memory  7.96 GB
>
> Available Physical Memory  5.18 GB
>
> Total Virtual Memory   15.9 GB
>
> Available Virtual Memory   12.8 GB
>
> Page File Space    7.96 GB
>
> **Times**
>
> -0.0124842039677 seconds to complete test loops
>
> make feature real time: 49.5458052658 seconds
>
> make feature computer time: 0.000226449800154
>
> join and calculate real time: 616.387228165
>
> join and calculate computer time: 0.000223139130561
>
> buffer and dissolve real time: 894.755151485
>
> buffer and dissolve computer time: 0.0110589607079

## Question

Why is Computer #2 the fastest when it has the fewest number of processors and far less memory than Computer #1?

Comment: I voted to close this as too broad because it is asking three questions when the [tour] says that there should be just one question asked per question.  I recommend that you remove the first sentence that starts "I'm looking for some input and collaboration" and focus on your third question - you may well find answers to your others as "by products" of answers to the third.

Comment: Timing information beyond a tenth of a millisecond is random noise.  Benchmarking is far more accurate when a thousand things are done several times, and the mean of those passes is reported.  Random noise could account multi-millisecond variance when a single thing is done once, rendering the differences moot.  I/O benchmarks must "prime the pump" by reading files before measuring access, lest subsequent runs be influenced by file I/O cache.

Comment: The only *GIS-ish* test you have is effectively an I/O benchmark, but nowhere is the disk device mentioned.  Disk is probably **the** most important piece of similarly configured GIS platforms.

Comment: Any suggestions on a more GIS-ish test to perform? I chose these because they're workflows that time intensive and done with some frequency.
Edited post based on PolyGeo comments.

Comment: As Vince points out,  you really need to run a given workflow N# of times and then average the results. Running 1 time and comparing against other single run is ripe with errors. N being hundreds, if not 1000s of executions. Plus, you Calc example, its just re-calcing the same thing on an already calc'd dataset. Not sure if thats a great test. On top of making sure you've isolated as many variables as possible (what other software is running on the machine, anti-virus? That could have a marginal impact). These are just _some_ of the things to watch for.

Comment: Thanks! I'll re-run one of these tests on a loop and average the results. I did restart the computer prior to starting the test and shutdown any non-essential processes prior to starting it.